# Style to conditionally flip an Icon horizontally { rotateY: '180deg'}

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I know it works because I have used it in the past, however this time around it is giving me a hard time and I ma not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
<Icon type={sensorKey}  style={sensorKey==='car'?[{...activityStyles.icon}, {transform: [{ rotateY: '180deg'}]}]:activityStyles.icon} size={Typography.bodyLineHeight} />
```

Comment: use transform: rotateY(180deg);

Comment: Please add some code which you are using. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just set: `transform: rotateY(180deg)`.

Answer (score 0):

We need you to provide an example of your html and css in order to give you the help you are asking for. Without it all we can do it guess.

But I will take a stab at it (note I added more for cross browser functionality):

```
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
transform: rotate(180deg);
```